# JS exporting / importing default and named export together

Tags: ecmascript-6, import, export

Sorry for the naming for the issue I select. This will most likely show how much confused I am :)

I am working on jhipster generated react project (really good structure, I liked it). What I want to do is to bind account menu item to store to include current user's login name. Current directory structure;

```
- .menus/account (exporting standart component and a default which is return value of connect HOC)
- .menus/admin
- .menus/user-management
- .menus/index.tsx
```

index.tsx exports all from the other account, admin, user-management

```
export * from 'acount'
export * from 'admin' ....
```

here, is there a possibility to import de default from account file ? or should I explicitly import it with another import statement ?

Comment: If I understood correctly what you want, then yes, you have to use another `import`

Comment: I bet you understand correct :)